# Можно ли в add_library cmake указать в какой файл поместить бинарники библиотеки?

Tags: cmake

Можно ли в add_library cmake указать в какой файл поместить бинарники библиотеки?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы имеете ввиду какое имя файла должно быть у библиотеки? Это можно сделать с помощью [команды](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/set_target_properties.html) :

```
set_target_properties( target1 target2
                  PROPERTIES prop1 value1
                  prop2 value2 ...)
```

указав в качестве `PROPERTY` `OUTPUT_NAME`.

Если вы все-таки имели ввиду в какую директорию поместить бинарники, то это можно сделать выставив переменным: [ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/prop_tgt/ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY.html) для статических либ, [RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/prop_tgt/RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY.html) для динамических библиотек и исполняемых файлов, необходимые значения.